# permalink editor doesn't show on custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a simple custom post type.
In my wordpress site, permalinks are set to Post Name.

In the admin screen for posts of my custom post type, no permalink editor is displayed.

How do I make this show up, as it does normally for the default post types?

This is how I've created the definition:

```
function register_cpt_staff_member() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'staff', 'staff-member' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'staff-member', 'staff-member' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'Staff Member' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Staff Member', 'staff_member' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Staff Member', 'staff_member' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Staff Member', 'staff_member' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Staff Member', 'staff_member' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Staff Members', 'staff_member' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No results found', 'staff_member' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No staff found in Trash', 'staff_member' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Staff Member:', 'staff_member' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Staff', 'Staff_member' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'public' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'staff_member', $args );
}
```

Comment: Share the code you are using for creating post type

Comment: Have you resaved your permalinks page to flush the permalinks. (This solves these problems 99% of the time!)

Comment: @AmitChauhan: I've updated the post to show my definition.

Comment: @mayerdesign: Yes. Every time I've altered the code I've flushed permalinks.

Comment: maybe the permalink editor is linked to "public => TRUE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CPT is not public, therefor the "posts" of that type have no reason to have a public URL (AKA permalink), therefor wordpress do not bother to add the permalink (actually slug) UI.

Comment: this may be technically accurate... however, if you want to programmatically access a non-public custom post type by it's post_name/slug... and if you want to change that post_name for identity/coding purposes... you can't using out-of-the-box WordPress (i consider that an oversight... sometimes dumbing it down is counterproductive)

Comment: maybe you should ask a question about your use case instead of claiming it is "oversight"

Answer (score -1):

```
function testimonials_custome_post(){
    $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'singular_name' => __('Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'add_new' => __('New Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add new Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'new_item' => __('New Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'view_item' => __('View Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'search_item' => __('Search Testimonials', 'testimonials'),
            'not_found' => __('No The Testimonials Found', 'testimonials'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No The Testimonials found in trash', 'testimonials')
        );
    $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-pressthis',
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                ),
        );

    register_post_type('testimonials', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'testimonials_custome_post' );
```

WORKING CODE FOR CUSTOM POST

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.